# Raspberry pi webserver as port forwarder

Tags: php, html, raspberry-pi, webserver

I was wondering if there is a program/web server which can display and forward ports via itself. For example I have a web server running on port 80 on my Pi,
And multiple web servers on a pc on different ports in the same network as the pi. Is it possible to host one webserver on port 80 on the pi which forwards you to the specified webserver. Preferably behind a password. An example of the layout would be multiple labeled buttons, and clicking on one of them would direct you to the specified webpage.

It would be ideal if the config file would be something like this:

Button_name: ('plex', 'wakeonlan') --different services.

Ipadress_and_port: ('192.168.0.100:78', 'localhost:81') -- here you would specify how the traffic would be routed.

(In this case plex would send you to 192.168.0.100:78 and clicking wakeonlan would send you to localhost:81)

Thanks In advance,
Sven